# Class not found when unmarshalling

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

Im trying to pass objects between fragments, and i use Parcelable interface.

Here is my class but something is messed up with the ArrayList property, as i got:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hu.company.myapp.modul.RaceDayUnit
```

and my class has an ArrayList of RaceDayUnits. All was worked properly until i started to use ArrayList.

Please help if you can.

My class:

```
public class RegattaUnit implements Parcelable {

public String id;
public String name;
public String type;
public String status;
public String token;

public ArrayList<RaceDayUnit> raceDays = new ArrayList<RaceDayUnit>();


public static class Status {
    public static String NEW = "invited";
    public static String JOINED = "joined";
    public static String DECLINED = "declined";
}

public RegattaUnit() {
}

// not used at all
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(id);
    out.writeString(name);
    out.writeString(type);
    out.writeString(status);
    out.writeString(token);
    out.writeList(raceDays);
}

private RegattaUnit(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    name = in.readString();
    type = in.readString();
    status = in.readString();
    token = in.readString();

    raceDays = new ArrayList<RaceDayUnit>();
    in.readList(raceDays, null);
}


public static final Creator<RegattaUnit> CREATOR = new Creator<RegattaUnit>() {

    public RegattaUnit createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new RegattaUnit(in);
    }

    public RegattaUnit[] newArray(int size) {
        return new RegattaUnit[size];
    }
};

 public RegattaUnit(JSONObject regattaJSONObject, String status) throws JSONException {

  //parsing from a jsonObject, the ArrayList is getting filled here.


    }




}


}
```

And log output:

```
04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257): Class not found when unmarshalling: hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RaceDayUnit
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RaceDayUnit
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:273)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2281)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readList(Parcel.java:1661)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RegattaUnit.<init>(RegattaUnit.java:58)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.RegattaUnit.<init>(RegattaUnit.java:14)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.RegattaUnit$1.createFromParcel(RegattaUnit.java:113)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.RegattaUnit$1.createFromParcel(RegattaUnit.java:110)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2252)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.service.GpsService.onStartCommand(GpsService.java:117)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2894)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RaceDayUnit" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     ... 28 more
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RaceDayUnit
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):         ... 29 more
    04-27 12:54:23.014: E/Parcel(9257):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
    04-27 12:54:23.015: D/AndroidRuntime(9257): Shutting down VM
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257): Process: hu.mycomp.myapp, PID: 9257
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service hu.mycomp.myapp.service.GpsService@16aad1da with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=hu.mycomp.myapp/.service.GpsService (has extras) }: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RaceDayUnit
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2911)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:151)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1401)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RaceDayUnit
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2295)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2245)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2526)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readList(Parcel.java:1661)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RegattaUnit.<init>(RegattaUnit.java:58)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RegattaUnit.<init>(RegattaUnit.java:14)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RegattaUnit$1.createFromParcel(RegattaUnit.java:113)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.modul.RegattaUnit$1.createFromParcel(RegattaUnit.java:110)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2252)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2152)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2485)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:918)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at hu.mycomp.myapp.service.GpsService.onStartCommand(GpsService.java:117)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2894)
    04-27 12:54:23.021: E/AndroidRuntime(9257):     ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than passing in `null` to `readList()` as the second parameter, pass in the `ClassLoader` that has `RaceUnit`. If `RegattaUnit` and `RaceUnit` are both in the same app and DEX file, `getClass().getClassLoader()` or `RaceUnit.class.getClassLoader()` should work.

(and now I am wondering what the SI unit of regatta actually is... :-)

Comment: Ok @commonsware, but what if I don't have any property list on my class, there is just primitive data types and still got the same error as Adam

Comment: @AlexSanchez: I recommend that you ask a fresh Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve], with your code and your stack trace.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38538751/1067450) is the question as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

It says classNotFoundException, so probably RaceDayUnit class not in your classpath. Have check hu.mycomp.myapp.modul package is in your source package?